# Wiener's Attack RSA

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I found this code of Wiener's attack on RSA

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WienerAttack {

// Four ArrayList for finding proper p/q which later on for guessing k/dg
List<BigInteger> d = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
List<Fraction> a = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
List<BigInteger> p = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
List<BigInteger> q = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
Fraction kDdg = new Fraction(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE); // k/dg, D
                                                                // means
                                                                // "divide"
private BigInteger e;
private BigInteger N;

// get the root of BigInteger number
public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger number) {
    BigInteger localBigInteger1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
    BigInteger localBigInteger2 = localBigInteger1.setBit(2 * number.bitLength());
    do {
        BigInteger localBigInteger3 = localBigInteger1.add(localBigInteger2);
        if (localBigInteger3.compareTo(number) != 1) {
            number = number.subtract(localBigInteger3);
            localBigInteger1 = localBigInteger3.add(localBigInteger2);
        }
        localBigInteger1 = localBigInteger1.shiftRight(1);
        localBigInteger2 = localBigInteger2.shiftRight(2);
    } while (localBigInteger2.bitCount() != 0);
    return localBigInteger1;
}

/**
 * Attacks given public key and modulos.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            public key
 * @param N
 *            modulos which needs to be factorized
 * @return
 */
public BigInteger attack(BigInteger e, BigInteger N) {
    this.e = e;
    this.N = N;
    int i = 0;
    BigInteger temp1;

    // This loop keeps going unless the privateKey is calculated or no
    // privateKey is generated
    // When no privateKey is generated, temp1 == -1
    while ((temp1 = step(i)) == null) {
        i++;
    }

    return temp1;
}

public BigInteger step(int iteration) {
    if (iteration == 0) {
        // initialization for iteration 0
        Fraction ini = new Fraction(e, N);
        d.add(ini.floor());
        a.add(ini.remainder());
        p.add(d.get(0));
        q.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    } else if (iteration == 1) {
        // iteration 1
        Fraction temp2 = new Fraction(a.get(0).denominator, a.get(0).numerator);
        d.add(temp2.floor());
        a.add(temp2.remainder());
        p.add((d.get(0).multiply(d.get(1))).add(BigInteger.ONE));
        q.add(d.get(1));
    } else {
        if (a.get(iteration - 1).numerator.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return BigInteger.ONE.negate(); // Finite continued fraction.
                                            // and no proper privateKey
                                            // could be generated. Return -1
        }

        // go on calculating p and q for iteration i by using formulas
        // stating on the paper
        Fraction temp3 = new Fraction(a.get(iteration - 1).denominator, a.get(iteration - 1).numerator);
        d.add(temp3.floor());
        a.add(temp3.remainder());
        p.add((d.get(iteration).multiply(p.get(iteration - 1)).add(p.get(iteration - 2))));
        q.add((d.get(iteration).multiply(q.get(iteration - 1)).add(q.get(iteration - 2))));
    }

    // if iteration is even, assign <q0, q1, q2,...,qi+1> to kDdg
    if (iteration % 2 == 0) {
        if (iteration == 0) {
            kDdg = new Fraction(d.get(0).add(BigInteger.ONE), BigInteger.ONE);
        } else {
            kDdg = new Fraction((d.get(iteration).add(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(p.get(iteration - 1)).add(
                    p.get(iteration - 2)), (d.get(iteration).add(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.get(iteration - 1))
                    .add(q.get(iteration - 2)));
        }
    }

    // if iteration is odd, assign <q0, q1, q2,...,qi> to kDdg
    else {
        kDdg = new Fraction(p.get(iteration), q.get(iteration));
    }

    System.out.println(kDdg);


    BigInteger  phi = e.multiply(kDdg.denominator).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(kDdg.numerator);
    BigInteger b = N.subtract(phi).add(BigInteger.ONE);
    BigInteger c = N;
    BigInteger descriminant = b.multiply(b).subtract(new BigInteger("4").multiply(c));
    BigInteger x1 = b.negate().add(sqrt(descriminant)).divide(new BigInteger("2")).abs();
    BigInteger x2 = b.negate().subtract(sqrt(descriminant)).divide(new BigInteger("2")).abs();

    if (x1.multiply(x2).equals(N)) {
        return e.modInverse(phi);
    }

    **BigInteger edg = this.e.multiply(kDdg.denominator); // get edg from e *
                                                        // dg

    // dividing edg by k yields a quotient of (p-1)(d-1) and a remainder of
    // g
    BigInteger fy = (new Fraction(this.e, kDdg)).floor();
    BigInteger g = edg.mod(kDdg.numerator);
    // get (p+d)/2 and check whether (p+d)/2 is integer or not
    BigDecimal pAqD2 = (new BigDecimal(this.N.subtract(fy))).add(BigDecimal.ONE).divide(new BigDecimal("2"));
    if (!pAqD2.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
        return null;
    // get [(p-d)/2]^2 and check [(p-d)/2]^2 is a perfect square or not
    BigInteger pMqD2s = pAqD2.toBigInteger().pow(2).subtract(N);
    BigInteger pMqD2 = sqrt(pMqD2s);
    if (!pMqD2.pow(2).equals(pMqD2s))
        return null;
    // get private key q from edg/eg
    BigInteger privateKey = edg.divide(e.multiply(g));
    return privateKey;**

}
}
```

In the bold code they do some tests extra x1.multiply(x2).equals(N) which means that N is factorized.

I put the following code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WienerAttack {

// Four ArrayList for finding proper p/q which later on for guessing k/dg
List<BigInteger> d = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
List<Fraction> a = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
List<BigInteger> p = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
List<BigInteger> q = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
Fraction kDdg = new Fraction(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE); // k/dg, D
                                                                // means
                                                                // "divide"
private BigInteger e;
private BigInteger N;

// get the root of BigInteger number
public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger number) {
    BigInteger localBigInteger1 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
    BigInteger localBigInteger2 = localBigInteger1.setBit(2 * number
            .bitLength());
    do {
        BigInteger localBigInteger3 = localBigInteger1
                .add(localBigInteger2);
        if (localBigInteger3.compareTo(number) != 1) {
            number = number.subtract(localBigInteger3);
            localBigInteger1 = localBigInteger3.add(localBigInteger2);
        }
        localBigInteger1 = localBigInteger1.shiftRight(1);
        localBigInteger2 = localBigInteger2.shiftRight(2);
    } while (localBigInteger2.bitCount() != 0);
    return localBigInteger1;
}

/**
 * Attacks given public key and modulos.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            public key
 * @param N
 *            modulos which needs to be factorized
 * @return
 */
public BigInteger attack(BigInteger e, BigInteger N) {
    this.e = e;
    this.N = N;
    int i = 0;
    BigInteger temp1;

    // This loop keeps going unless the privateKey is calculated or no
    // privateKey is generated
    // When no privateKey is generated, temp1 == -1
    while ((temp1 = step(i)) == null) {
        i++;
    }

    return temp1;
}

public BigInteger step(int iteration) {
    if (iteration == 0) {
        // initialization for iteration 0
        Fraction ini = new Fraction(e, N);
        d.add(ini.floor());
        a.add(ini.remainder());
        p.add(d.get(0));
        q.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    } else if (iteration == 1) {
        // iteration 1
        Fraction temp2 = new Fraction(a.get(0).denominator,
                a.get(0).numerator);
        d.add(temp2.floor());
        System.out.println("d = " + temp2.floor());
        a.add(temp2.remainder());
        System.out.println("remainder = " + temp2.remainder());
        p.add((d.get(0).multiply(d.get(1))).add(BigInteger.ONE));
        System.out.println("p = "
                + (d.get(0).multiply(d.get(1))).add(BigInteger.ONE));
        q.add(d.get(1));
        System.out.println("q = " + d.get(1));

    } else {
        if (a.get(iteration - 1).numerator.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return BigInteger.ONE.negate(); // Finite continued fraction.
                                            // and no proper privateKey
                                            // could be generated. Return -1
        }

        // go on calculating p and q for iteration i by using formulas
        // stating on the paper
        Fraction temp3 = new Fraction(a.get(iteration - 1).denominator,
                a.get(iteration - 1).numerator);
        d.add(temp3.floor());
        a.add(temp3.remainder());
        p.add((d.get(iteration).multiply(p.get(iteration - 1)).add(p
                .get(iteration - 2))));
        q.add((d.get(iteration).multiply(q.get(iteration - 1)).add(q
                .get(iteration - 2))));
    }

    // if iteration is even, assign <q0, q1, q2,...,qi+1> to kDdg
    if (iteration % 2 == 0) {
        if (iteration == 0) {
            kDdg = new Fraction(d.get(0).add(BigInteger.ONE),
                    BigInteger.ONE);
        } else {
            kDdg = new Fraction((d.get(iteration).add(BigInteger.ONE))
                    .multiply(p.get(iteration - 1)).add(
                            p.get(iteration - 2)),
                    (d.get(iteration).add(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(
                            q.get(iteration - 1)).add(q.get(iteration - 2)));
        }
    }

    // if iteration is odd, assign <q0, q1, q2,...,qi> to kDdg
    else {
        kDdg = new Fraction(p.get(iteration), q.get(iteration));
    }

    System.out.println(kDdg);

    BigInteger phi = e.multiply(kDdg.denominator).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
            .divide(kDdg.numerator); // from formula phi = (ed -1) / t
    BigInteger b = N.subtract(phi).add(BigInteger.ONE);
    BigInteger c = N;
    BigInteger descriminant = b.multiply(b).subtract(
            new BigInteger("4").multiply(c));
    BigInteger x1 = b.negate().add(sqrt(descriminant))
            .divide(new BigInteger("2")).abs();
    BigInteger x2 = b.negate().subtract(sqrt(descriminant))
            .divide(new BigInteger("2")).abs();

    if (x1.multiply(x2).equals(N)) {
        return e.modInverse(phi); // private key found
    } else {
        return null;
    }
   }
```

Are the first tests of the first code really necessary? Or the code below works just fine with no restrictions comparing to the first code?